# Google Apps script: How to play audio file on google drive with button click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-apps-script

I've used some existing code to create a web app that records an audio file and saves it to my google drive. I'd like to include a 'message' button that plays an audiofile when clicked, although this doesn't seem to work for me... everything else works as expected. Would really appreciate any advice and suggestions.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Lame.js Upload Example</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
</head>

<body style="padding-top: 60px">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text-center">
            <div>
                <h3 class="text-center" id="timer"></h3>
            </div>
            <img src="https://img.freepik.com/premium-photo/rotary-phone-dial-white-background_476612-10274.jpg?w=1380" width="400" height="300">
            <br><br>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="messageBtn">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i> Message
            </button>

            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="startBtn">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-record"></i> Start
            </button>

            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="stopBtn" disabled="true">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></i> Stop
            </button>

            <ol class="convertedList" style="display:none"></ol>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?!= Include.js(['worker-realtime','mic']); ?>
<script>
    //on document ready
    $(function () {
        var recorder = new MP3Recorder({
            bitRate: 128
        }), timer;


        $('#startBtn').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var btn = $(this);
            recorder.start(function () {
                //start timer,
                var seconds = 0, updateTimer = function(){
                    $('#timer').text(seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds);
                };
                timer = setInterval(function () {
                    seconds++;
                    updateTimer();
                }, 1000);
                updateTimer();
                //disable start button
                btn.attr('disabled', true);
                $('#stopBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
            }, function () {
                alert('We could not make use of your microphone at the moment');
            });
        });


        $('#stopBtn').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            recorder.stop();
            $(this).attr('disabled', true);
            $('#startBtn').removeAttr('disabled');
            //get MP3
            clearInterval(timer);
            recorder.getMp3Blob(function (blob) {
                //var blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                blobToDataURL(blob, function(url){
                   var filename = 'recording_' +
                            (new Date()) +
                            '_.mp3';
                   google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(driveUrl){
                     //do nothing
                   }).invokeSave(url, filename);
                });
            }, function (e) {
                alert('We could not retrieve your message');
                console.log(e);
            });
        });


        function getAudioUrl(callback) {
             var fileId = "file ID here";
             var path = $("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + fileId).val();
              callback(path);
        }

       $('#messageBtn').on('click', function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             getAudioUrl(function(url) {
             var audio = new Audio(url);
             audio.preload = 'auto';
             audio.src = url;
             audio.play();
           });
        });
        
        function blobToDataURL(blob, callback) {
            var a = new FileReader();
            a.onload = function (e) {
                callback(e.target.result);
            }
            a.readAsDataURL(blob);
        }

    });
</script>
</body>
```

Where this chunk of code is where I create a 'message button' and attempt to playback an audiofile from my drive:

```
        function getAudioUrl(callback) {
             var fileId = "file ID here";
             var path = $("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + fileId).val();
              callback(path);
        }

       $('#messageBtn').on('click', function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             getAudioUrl(function(url) {
             var audio = new Audio(url);
             audio.preload = 'auto';
             audio.src = url;
             audio.play();
           });
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var path = $("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + fileId).val();
```

#### To:

```
var path = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + fileId;
```

- I'm worried that in this case, the file of `fileId` might be required to be publicly shared. If this modification didn't work, please share publicly the file of `fileId` and test it again.